# It's possibleto render multiple scatter chart in chart-js with second y-axis as caterory?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I want to create a multiple scatter graphs as similar as in the picture? Is it even possible to render this using only chart-js library?? I can't figure it out - how can I define datasets to render like this. Maybe someone have already built this (or maybe using another library?) Thanks!

So, the x axis is a timestamp, y-axis-left - refers to each graph, and the y-axis-right is kind of category(each number is a category - i.e. the different graph)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCbYZ.png)

I have no idea how to create something like this. Only if I render multiple scatter charts one above another, but not using only one scatter component (chart)..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by stacking multiple y-axis
You can take a look at this link: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/stacked.html

For the Dataset id axis, you can write something like this (it is just a hint, not a final solution):

```
const config = {
 [...],
  options: {
    scales: {
       y3:{
          type: 'category',
          position:"right",
          display:true,
          labels:[1,2,3], // Here you should get the number of dataset that you have, to make it generic
       }
     }
   }
```